# React Native, content going under navigation header, SafeAreaView not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

As you can see in the image below, I have to give some top margin in order to "not" hide my half of the content under the navigation header, isn't header supposed to be a "safe area" for the below content, to be on the safe side I provided the `SafeAreaView` but still my content goes under the Header and unfortunately I have to give some hardcoded margin top value to avoid hiding.

[image]

The above image is when I comment `marginTop`.

[image]

Above image is when I add `marginTop: 70`

Code:

`NotificationScreen.tsx`:

```js
import {
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import Animated, {FadeIn, FadeOut} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import OrderItem from '../../components/OrderItem';

const NotificationScreen = () => {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // calling API...
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="transparent" translucent />

      <Text style={{color: 'lightgray', fontSize: 18}}>My Orders: </Text>

      <Animated.FlatList
        data={orders}
        entering={FadeIn}
        leaving={FadeOut}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
        keyExtractor={(_: any, index) => 'key' + index}
        renderItem={({item}) => <OrderItem key={item.id} data={item} />}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 70, // if I remove this, the content goes under the header as shown in image.
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
  },
});

export default NotificationScreen;
```

One more query, why my `OrderItem` not taking the full width of `FlatList` (see image, the gray box is not takin the full width...), I have provided `width: 100%` to my `OrderItem` container:

`OrderItem.tsx`:

```js
const OrderItem = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.textBlock}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>Strategy: </Text>
        <Text style={styles.info}>{data.strategyTitle}</Text>
      </View>
      // ... same views as shown in image
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: COLORS.lightGray,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  textBlock: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  label: {
    color: 'grey',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  info: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default OrderItem;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `SafeAreaView` does not work currently for Android devices. You need to set a dynamic `paddingTop` to avoid this issue:

```js
import { Platform, StatusBar } from "react-native";
```

```js
<SafeAreaView
  style={{
    paddingTop: Platform.OS == "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
  }}
>
  {/* Your screen elements go here */}
</SafeAreaView>
```

And for the `OrderItem` not taking all available width, remove from `Animated.FlatList` this:

```
contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'center'}}
```